# Jasperserver QRCode not visible in generated report

Tags: qr-code, jasperserver

I Have created a jrmxl report using JasperStudio that just has a QRCode (Barcode4j)

```
<band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
    <componentElement>
        <reportElement x="144" y="50" width="100" height="30" uuid="bd83d632-c2b7-47a2-957a-7fa5483e6002"/>
        <jr:QRCode xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
            <jr:codeExpression><![CDATA["123456789"]]></jr:codeExpression>
        </jr:QRCode>
    </componentElement>
</band>
```

When i preview the report via Jasper Studio, it shows the QR Code. But when the report is published under JasperServer the QRCode does not appear in the report.There are no errors in the server.log file

According to this link [Barcode4J QR Code](http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/trunk/symbol-qr.html) need to use [Zxing Core jar](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/zxing/core/3.2.1/).

I have tried dropping the core.jar file in the WEB-INF/lib  as per [enter link description here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/801356/help-needed-import-jar-jasper-server).

Can confirm that the barcode4j-2.1.jar exists in the WEB-INF/lib.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following property to *WEB-INF/classes/jasperreports.properties* file:

`net.sf.jasperreports.components.barcode4j.image.producer=image`

Comment: Add libraries core-2.2.jar and javase-2.2.jar to /opt/jasperreports-server-cp-6.4.3/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/lib